# How to export static HTML/CSS from XD

Tags: html, css

I have a project that was designed in adobe XD. is there any way to export or convert in css and html and use in code editor? 
or I have to design by myself code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/peterflynn/xd-copy-css-code

I found this and can get basic CSS format from this repo url. I recommend you try it.